# Axios Post React Native Return Undefined Sometimes

Tags: react-native, axios

Why my axios post return undefined sometimes ?

Check this code :

```
export const ApiConfigAxios = axios.create({    
    // * Begin =========================== Configuration API

    baseURL: 'https://website.id/index.php',    
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",                              
        "Authorization": `Basic ${base64data}`,        
    },    

    // * End =========================== Configuration API

});


export const ApiRegisterOrLoginUser = async (email, name, picture, givenname, familyname) => {               
    try {
        // * Begin =========================== API    
        
        const response = await ApiConfigAxios.post('/AuthenticationAPI', {        
            email: email,
            name: name,
            picture: picture,
            givenname: givenname,        
            familyname: familyname,                                        
        });

        // * End =========================== API     
  
    
        
        if (response.data.Data.length === 2) {           
            let results = Object.assign(response.data.Data[0], response.data.Data[1]);            
            return results;
        } else {                    
            return response.data;
        }
        

    } catch (err) {                                 
        console.error(err);       
    }    
};
```

**The Problem Is :**

When I clear data app from android setting and open the app then quickly click the sign in button I will got **undefined**

But when I clear data app from android setting and open the app then wait at least 3 second before click the sign in button it is **working**

what is the problem with the axios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

The problem is in server side. I have a **post value (TOKENS)** that cannot be null.
That is a **Notification Tokens**. It is inside **useEffect.**
So in my app I check **if TOKENS != null** (delay until the token generate) then the button login show.

Also to make a better user experience when got undefined I check in my API Axios :

```
 if (typeof response == 'undefined') {
     return "FAILED";    
 }
```

When user login and receive **undefined** I will prompt a **Message Box** rather than loading without end. So user can try login again.